# default tab controller doesn't fit with Flutter list view builder scroll

Tags: dart

I have a profile page in which theres a default tab controller.

```
Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      CircleAvatar(),
      Text(
      "state.eu.username",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
      ),
      DetailedTab(
      domainExpertise: domainExpertise,
      eu: eu,
      ),
    ],
  ));
```

This is the tab view :

```
 return DefaultTabController(
length: 4,
child: Column(
  children: [
    TabBar(
      labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 5, 8, 0),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
      indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      labelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      unselectedLabelColor:
          Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.3),
      isScrollable: true,
      tabs: [
        Container(
          width: 120,
          child: Tab(
            text: 'Domain Expertise',)),
        Tab(
          text: 'Sessions'),
        Tab(
          text: 'Subscription',),
        Tab(
          text: 'Reviews',)
      ],
    ),
    Divider(
      height: 1,
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.3),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 350,
      child: TabBarView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        children: <Widget>[
        widget1,
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 30),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              child: UpcomingSessionsListTile().upcomingSessionsListTile(currentUserName: widget.eu.username)),
        ),
        widget3,widget4,
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
));
```

I wanted to solve this scroll : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVpLz.jpg  thats happening but cant figure out whats wrong. widget2 returns a list view builder.I can't make out why tab controller is behaving like a stack and the scroll is going beneath it for it should just behave normal.  How can I resolve it so that the list don't scroll to the very top.

This is the List View Builder thats getting returned :

```
 ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: 20,
  itemBuilder: (((context, index) {
    return PreviousSessionCard(
      trailing: Container(
        height: 0,
        width: 0,
      ),
      sessionWith: "Session",
      sessionTime: "timeString",
      onTap: () {},
      padd: false,
    );
  })))
```

And this would be the PreviousSessionCard :

```
 class PreviousSessionCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String sessionWith;
  final String sessionTime;
  final Function onTap;
  final bool padd;
  final String day;
  final Widget trailing;
  PreviousSessionCard(
      {Key key,
      this.sessionWith,
      this.sessionTime,
      this.onTap,
      this.padd = true,
      this.day,
      this.trailing})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: padd ? 15.0 : 0.0, vertical: padd ? 6.0 : 0.0),
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: onTap,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        tileColor: Colors.white,
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          radius: 25,
          child: ClipOval(
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/images/profile.svg',
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          )),
        ),
        trailing: trailing ??
            Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                size: 15.0, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        title: Text(sessionWith,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 18.0,
              // color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            )),
        subtitle: Text(
          sessionTime,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            fontSize: 14,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where is `DefaultTabController` called ?

Comment: Please produce the entire minimal reproducible code. so that i can run in my device and let you know the problem

Comment: DetailedTab widget is a statefult widget that returns Default Tab Controller. Forgot to mention

Comment: I have updated the code in the question, you can have a look